# Customized search result

Tags: nodes, search

I have a content type let's say content type 'A', I am using view to show some of the field on some page, Now the problem is that pages generated by the content type are just a junk because I am not showing it to uses , only i am showing it using view page/block. Problem: I don't want to show those junk page in Search result  , Plz let me know how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a content type from search results](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45502/remove-a-content-type-from-search-results)

Comment: Also you may want the rabbit_hole module to stop users viewing the actual node page at the node/NID URL.

Comment: @rooby I prefer global redirect for that, works more... globally ;)

Comment: @molot: Sorry I didn't specifically mean the node/NID URL but the node page in general, because the OP says they don't want to show node pages to users because they exclusively use views for that (if I understood correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve required customization by using [Search configuration](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_config) module.

additional things can be done with the modules are:

1. Alter the appearance of the core node search form.
2. Group content types for more meaningful searching
3. **Restrict search results by the content type. This is a role based
   restriction.**
4. Restrict search results from showing individual items.
5. Alter the pager limit (aka number search item results per page).

Answer (score 0):

If you are still using the search from core, you should switch to for example search_api.

That beeing sayed, if you wish to avoid installing another contrib module and are willing to implement the functionality as a part of custom module. You could set excluded node types (programmatically) and then use hook_query_alter to filter out those types from each search.

Comment: This is not necessary but is an option. You don't have to write code to do what the OP asks.

Comment: Added note that this answer suggestion is for the cases where keeping contrib module count low is preferred. It would be nice to have answer type taxonomy here, so "theres a module for that" and "diy" answers could be separated or even accepted as alternative.